# the return statement of C in a function

Tags: c, function, return

I am a newbie of C language, I have a question about `return` statement in C:

```
void verifyValue(int value)
{
   return;
}

void handleValue(int value)
{
   switch(value)
   {
      case 1:
         // do something
         break;

      case 10:
         verifyValue(value);
         // the rest of code part 1
         break;
      default:
         break;           
   }
}

int main()
{
   int vlaue = 10;
   handleValue(value);

   // the rest of code part 2
}
```

so the `verifyValue()` function will return in `case 10`, once it returns, will the rest of code part 1 continue to execute or the rest of code part 2 continue to execute, from where this return in `verifyValue()` really returned?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'part 1' and 'part 2'? Each respective `return` statement will return from the function is is contained within.

Comment: Isn't this more easier to test with some print statements rather than posting a question here?

Comment: Can you test with a debugger? Being able to use a debugger in C is more important than learning the language itself.

Comment: yes, you are right, I did debug it myself, sometimes I need to understand how it really works, so I ask a question here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case 10:
         verifyValue(value);
         // the rest of code part 1
         break;
```

`verifyValue()` function is called and after returning from that function

> // the rest of code part 1

is executed.
After that `break` is executed so you get out of `switch` construct.

Later the control is returned to `main()` and

> // the rest of code part 2

is executed.

Answer (score 0):

After `verifyValue()` call the break statement will work first which will bring the control outside the switch case. after that the handleValue function will return and then "the rest of code part 2" will continue.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement only returns from the function in which it's executed.  So this function:

```
void verifyValue(int value)
{
    return;
}
```

doesn't do anything.  It just immediately returns.  Invoking that function has no effect on the logic flow of the code.

"The rest of code part 1" will execute.  Then the `handleValue()` function will implicitly return when it reaches the end of the function.  Then "the rest of code part 2" will execute.

Answer (score 0):

The return statement causes the immediate termination of the invoked function,so,the return statement in verifyvalue function terminates the function and does not end the handlevalue function.The execution continues after that point.