# How does the return statement work in C?

Tags: c, return

I have a question about return statement in C, from where it really returns:

```
int base(int a)
{
   if(a == 1)
     return 0;
}

int inherit()
{
   base(1);
   // the rest of the code
}
```

So within the `inherit()` function, `base()` is called, and it executes `return 0`, in this case; does the rest of code in `inherit()` still execute? How does the return statement really work?

Comment: `inherit` calls `base`. Base *returns* a value, which you could capture in `inherit` with something like, `int ret = base(1);`. But it doesn't. It calls `base(1)` without capturing the return value. So the return value is ignored.

Comment: Please notice that `base()` does not *always* return a value calling it with `a != 1` invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: An optimizing compiler would not produce any code at all ;-).

Comment: @PeterSchneider: that's not entirely accurate.  Since the two functions are both externally visible, the compiler is obliged to generate code so that the functions can be called from other source files.  However, it might make `inherit()` into an empty function because it can see that calling `base()` does nothing useful (and there's nothing else shown in `inherit()`, though the comment indicates there's other code there.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler True, "at all" was said too much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32458457/the-return-statement-of-c-in-a-function/32467074#32467074

Comment: If you found it interesting, maybe you should learn a little about assembly ?

Comment: "How does the return statement work in C?" -- Just fine, thanks. 8-)}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is a little too minimal for comfort.  I'd feel happier with:

```
int base(int a)
{
    if (a == 1)
        return 0;
    return 37;
}

int inherit(void)
{
    int n = base(1);
    printf("Base(1) is %d\n", n);
    return n + 3;
}
```

When `inherit()` calls `base()`, its current state is stored, the function `base()` is run, and it returns a value.  In this code, the return value is captured in a variable, `n` and that is then used in the `printf()` call and the `return` within `inherit()`.  That's how `return` works: it unilaterally stops the execution of the current function and continues in the calling function.

Even in `main()`, a `return` terminates the current function and returns a value to the calling function, which is the C runtime — and the C runtime ensures that the process exits, usually relaying the returned value to the 'environment' (a shell program on Unix, for example).

Note that the revised code ensures that `base()` always returns a value.  Not doing so would lead to undefined behaviour in general.  If the function is only ever called with the value `1` as an argument, it would be 'OK', but then why are you calling the function in the first place.  So, always ensure that if a function is supposed to return a value, all returns from the function (including, in particular, the one at the end of the function) returns a value.  In the original code, there is no `return` at the end — that's bad!

Comment: Hm, this sentence " That's how return works: it unilaterally stops the execution of the current function and continues in the calling function [correct till here, p.s.] until the called function returns [it just did!?], whereupon execution resumes in the calling function." is a little fuzzy. The called function returned upon `return`, and the call*ing* function just continues as ususal after that.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: thanks. I agree. I've removed the second end of the sentence.

Comment: I'd like to know the etiquette here: would it be ok to edit that right away? Would you mind, would anybody mind? (I wouldn't.) In such cases when it is very likely just an editing error (I thiink you mixed a sentence about calling with one about returning).

Comment: @PeterSchneider: yes, it would have been OK to make the edit.  I would have been notified that you'd made the edit, and would have checked it, but would have left it with at least mental thanks (would you have picked up on those?).

Answer (score 1):

If you call `return` in your code, the code in that function will stop working once it reaches that point.  Control will then move back to the function that called it, or the program will end, depending on where in your program the return is located.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it continues to execute the rest of the code. The `base` method returns only on an explicit `return` in it. This counts also for the `inherit` method.

If you want the `inherit` method return the value of `base` add the `return` keyword.

```
int inherit()
{
   return base(1);
   // the rest of the code can now be left out actually
}
```

Nitpick:
In your example the compiler will probably complain, as there is no return value in case `a != 1`.
So you would have to add something like

```
int base(int a)
{
   if(a == 1)
     return 0;
   else
     return 1;
}
```

Comment: I think the OP was more interested in whether the inherit() method returns as well ;-).

Answer (score 1):

> So within the inherit() function, base() is called, and it return 0, in this case, does the rest of code in inherit() still execute?

Yes , it will execute . `return` in function `base` will give back control (or value ) to calling function.

And then the rest of the calling function `inherit()` will be executed until its scope ends or `return` is encountered in `inherit()` .

*Note* - function `base` should also `return` value if the `if` condition is not met . As pointed by others if not it will invoke undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

If you write

```
int inherit()
{
  int x=99;

  x=base(1);

  dothis();
  // the rest of the code
}
```

Then x is now 0 and the program goes the next line dothis();

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of the `return` statement is defined by the ISO C standard. Quoting the [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft, section 6.8.6.4:

> A **`return`** statement terminates execution of the current function and
>   returns control to its caller. A function may have any number of
>   **`return`** statements.
>
> If a **`return`** statement with an expression is executed, the value of the
>   expression is returned to the caller as the value of the function call
>   expression. If the expression has a type different from the return
>   type of the function in which it appears, the value is converted as if
>   by assignment to an object having the return type of the function.

So if you have a function like:

```
int func(void) {
    return 42;
}
```

and you call it from some other function (or even from the same function; see *recursion*):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int result = func();
    printf("%d\n", result);
}
```

then the function call `func()` is an *expression* that yields the value `42`.

A function defined with a return type of `void` doesn't return a value. A `return` statement in such a function is just `return;` with no expression. It terminates execution of the function, but no value is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't returned the result of `base`, there is no reason why `inherit` won't execute the rest of lines.

The function keeps on executing until it reaches a `return` statement. in `inherit` it met a function call - `base`. calling a function which returns a value doesn't mean returning that result.

For example, if someone sends me to fetch a receipt from a store - the fact that that store gave me a receipt doesn't mean I neccesarily gave it to the one who sent me in the first place.

This, on the other hand, will return the result of `base` and won't execute the rest of the code.

```
int inherit()
{
   return base(1);
   // the rest of the code
}
```

Comment: The posted code potentially invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @iharob probably, but I guess the OP wanted more conceptual answer on return statements rather than concrete code review.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after calling `base()`, the code will continue to run but with ***[undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)***.  The edits below illustrate capturing the return value and using it in a branch statement.  You should always include a return statement for a non-void function:

```
int base(int a)
{
   if(a == 1)
     return 0;
   else return -1;//function is provided alternative return path
}

int inherit()
{
   int status = base(1);
   if(status == 0)
   {
      // the rest of the code
   }
   return status;
}
```

Comment: Still undefined behaviour if `a != 1`

Comment: also *base()* should always return something

Comment: @Bathsheba  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The return statement returns a value that the caller can use. The return value does not influence anything in the caller's code, other than when the caller uses the value (e.g. in checking the value in an `if` statement). Once the return is executed, the called function stops executing and any local variables have been released.

The return statement can return a single, word-sized value such as an int or a pointer. In newer C versions the return statement can return composite values (e.g. a struct); in that case the compiler immediately performs a copy operation because the struct returned could have been a local (automatic) variable of the called function. As these variables are allocated on the stack, they will be destroyed (overwritten) with the next call by the caller; hence, the compiler must save them immediately. Note that returning a pointer to a local (automatic) variable of the called function is an error, as the variable will have been released upon return and can have been overwritten.

Often the valued returned is returned in a register. Traditionally in Intel this is the `eax` register.

Examples:

```
 return i;    // return the value of an int.
 return p;    // return a pointer p

 struct MY_STRUCT S= {0};   // local struct S is on the stack
 return S;                  // return the whole structure
 //caller:
 struct MY_STRUCT S2= myFunction(); // compiler copies S to S2

struct MY_STRUCT S= {0};    // local struct S is on the stack
return &S;                  // return pointer to S !!error:
//caller:
struct MY_STRUCT *S= myFunction();  // S will be overwritten with nex call!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Not considering the obvious mistake of missing a return value:

```
int inherit(){
 int return_value =  base(1);
 // ------^
 // the rest of the code
}
```

> How does the return statement really work?

For function calls (in your case `inherit()` calls `base()`) we need to return to the instruction following the function call so that the program continues its execution cycle. This return requires two pieces of information:

1.**A `return` statement** indicates the end of execution of a function and has the same semantics on both low level and high level languages.<sup>1</sup>

2.**Return address**: how the processor knows where to return after a completing a function call? This piece of information is normally stored when the function is called. So, when a function is called, among other things<sup>2</sup>, the return address is stored. Two special places are mostly used: a special register or the stack. Thus, when `return` statement is reached the *flow of control* is transferred to the address of the instruction following the *function call*<sup>3</sup>.

In addition to that you can return a specific values e.g. result of a computation, etc, as predefined *returning type* in the function signature whose value has no direct implication on whether the execution will continue or not. In your case, if you return any other valid value of type `int` from your function `base()`, it will have undefined implication of the rest of the execution, because `base()` does not provide a return statement for all possible inputs, which will lead to *undefined behaviour*.

> Does the rest of code in `inherit()` still execute?

For the value you are calling it, i.e.:`1` it continues to execute whatever follows in `inherit()` after the `base()` function returns its value.

---

<sup>1. High level languages allow default fall-through mechanism. That is, if we don't explicitly specify the end of a procedure, control is returned at the end of the block.</sup>

<sup>2. Modifies the PC (program counter).</sup>

<sup>3. The actual return address stored depends on the processor. Some
processors such as the SPARC store the address of the call instruction itself. Others
such as the MIPS and the Pentium store the address of the instruction following the call
instruction.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> C is Procedure Oriented Programming langauge and unlike OOP the focus
>   is on is on variable, Data Structures & Subroutines.(However here OOP also works the same way)

When your program is executing in

> int inherit() function

it makes a call to

> int base(int a)

supplying a value of 1 for a.This is a subroutine.Since, a subroutine is essentially a group of computational instructions grouped by the programmer for various reasons which might be ease of coding or better organization,etc.

After the `base(1);` subroutine finishes execution the next instruction loaded/executed is the one which immediately follows it.

For now you need to know that Your inherit() function keeps on executing until it encounters a code which signals it to stop.the most common of which are

```
exit(0);//exit entire program
return val;//where val stores an integer(control returns to calling function,or program exits if it the only function
```

After the above code is executed in a function/routine all code below it in the same function doesn't execute)

You could even return from a void function by typing :

```
return;
```