# Max of 4 numbers using another function (max of 2)

Tags: c

This is about how I can use a function inside another function. I'm trying to get the max of 4 numbers using another function that determines the max of 2. The errors I get are

> expected expression before int

and

> to few arguments to function max2

I tried to search what they mean however I didn't really understand much... thank you for any help

```
int max2(int a, int b) {
        if(a > b) {
            printf("%d is the max\n", a);
        }
        else {
            printf("%d is the max\n", b);
        }
}



int max4(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
        
        if(a > b)
        {
            if(a > c)
            {
                max2(int a, int d);
            }
            else
            {
                max2(int c, int d);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(b > c)
            {
                max2(int b, int d);
            }
            else
            {
                max2(int c, int d);
            }
        }
} 

int main() {
    max4(666,853,987,42);
}
```

Comment: This function design doesn't make a whole lot of sense. You should be using a `for` loop which searches through an array, ideally placed inside a single function.

Comment: ok good to know i have no idea what i'm doing. i actually got it using the for loop in an array. However i thought that maybe i could figure it out using another function to solve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare functions returning `int`, but those functions return nothing. Probably you'd want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max2 (int a, int b) { return a > b ? a : b; }
int max4 (int a, int b, int c, int d) { return max2(max2(a, b), max2(c, d)); }

int main (void) {
        printf("%d is the max\n", max4(666,853,987,42));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to programming!

You should take a closer look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm) to see why you are incorrectly **calling** (important keyword) your function.
 Additionally you should look into the `return` keyword. (A quick look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32972391/17514712) or the more in depth [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/return-statement-c?view=msvc-170) should help)

Also, as mentioned in the comments, your solution is a bit weird.
 Try finding the max of 20 numbers, by using [`for`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm) or [`while`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_while_loop.htm) loops, as well as an [array](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm).

Happy learning!